# formatting DateTime as string in JSON using Gson

Tags: java, json, gson

I'm trying to format my DateTime attribute as a String using Gson. I now do this using 
`Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssX").create();`
but it doesn't work.

current output: `"startTijd":{"date":{"year":2016,"month":10,"day":16},"time":{"hour":14,"minute":0,"second":0,"nano":0}}`

required output (ISO 8061): `2016-10-16'T'14:0:0:0X`

Comment: How do you serialize  the Date? (E.g please post the code where you call the serialization method(s))

Comment: I don't but that's my problem I guess, thank you!

Comment: Please post your serialization code.